# Calculating all resources loaded on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-load-time

I am loading a page which has CSS + images + scripts . So I want to calculate all the number of total resources loaded onto the page on runtime on page load So that i can show a progressbar based on that calculations and a little bit of load time .

My question is how to calculate how many number of resources are actually loaded into the dom including images + scripts + css files . And based on that I need to calculate the progressbar progress pattern and make it proceed .

Can someone throw some light how to do that ?

Comment: Doesn't the browser already provide a progress indicator for that? I thought that was what the browser is there for.

Answer (score 0):

The total number is:

```
$('script, link[type=text/css], img').size();
```

This will return the total number of resources your requested.

Comment: `length` isn't a function, use `.length;` or `.size();`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a straight forward way to do this. Script and image tags has the load event, so you can attach a callback and know when they are loaded. Css has no events or properties to query, however you can use a workaround using an img tag. 
But this is not so simple because if you attach a callback to a script tag that is already loaded, that callback will never fire up, same for img tags.
So when your progress bar start to track all img/script/css on the document, it will need to know what img/script/css is already loaded and then attach an event callback for the others that are not loaded yet. Img tags has a `complete` property, but script do not, so you cannot know if a script is loaded or not by simply querying the DOM. Css is more trick.

Well, as you can see this is not a simple task, actually it is complicated and personally I do not think it's worth spending time and effort into it just to *display a progress bar*.

Display a old and good spin in your page and be happy :)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right on your point . But there is a silverlight application running just twin to our site . So we are supposed to implement the same jus with Mvc platform . So Was looking to tweak around with how I may proceed . Your understanding of my query is perfect though . Is there any suitable easier method ?

Comment: @Joy, no easier solution that I know about. You can attach and load event for scripts and images and display a less accurate progress bar. What I can say to you is that I tried this before and the thing not worked very well. For example, if you show a progress bar you have to hide it after all resources are loaded, right? What if an image fails to load or a script fails to load?

Comment: You can try to use markers on your scripts to display something. For example, when a script load it calls and "loaded("xyz")" so you can display some information about the progress. But for images and css there is no reliable way I think.

Comment: Hmm thanks ... I got your point abt that ... Your statements really helped me :) i cant mark it as a straight forward answer though as of now . But I would definitely upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

##### This a Vanilla Javascript, more complete answer following @Alaa Badran's answer

It only counts the number of elements of the page, but you might create a counter from this to get how many elements are left to load.

It counts all loaded CSS stylesheets as well as all HTML elements that support loading external contents with the "src" attribute (so it avoids counting "placeholders" elements, initially not loading external contents)

```js
function countElementsLoadingContent() {
  // Counts the number of elements loading content on the page
  const htmlTagsLoadingContent = [
    "img",
    "script",
    "video",
    "audio",
    "iframe", 
    "source", 
    "track", 
    "embed", 
    "object"
  ]
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(htmlTagsLoadingContent.join(','))
  let elementsWithSrc = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].src) {
      elementsWithSrc++
    }
  }

  const cssLinks = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')

  const totalElements = elementsWithSrc + cssLinks.length
  console.log(`Total elements on the page that load content: ${totalElements}`)
  return totalElements
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off searching for `link[rel=stylesheet]` as the MIME type is not recommended for many years now. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attributes

Answer (score -1):

I think you're approaching the problem the wrong way around...

If your page is so big that it needs a progress bar then it's probably too big.

Why not optimise the page so that it starts rendering quickly and the other items are added in afterwards e.g. progressively or lazy loaded.

Comment: no the  Page isn't  very big . But whats the problem is actually I have mentioned in devundef's comment . Please read that . I think he understood my area of query perfectly :)